# Finding login attempts to a MacBook Pro

Tags: mojave, login

Is there a way I can see the login attempts and login status to my MacBook Pro? These are essentially user sign-ins. Running macOS Mojave 10.14.4.

Answer (score 1):

Open Console and search for "login" in the search box.

In a terminal, do

```
grep -i login /var/log/system.log
```

For finding failed attempts, use

```
grep -i authe /var/log/system.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `last` command to see a running history of logins. For example here's the most recent 10 lines from the `last` command:

```
$ last -10
joeuser  ttys012                   Tue Apr  9 08:01 - 08:01  (00:00)
joeuser  ttys011                   Mon Apr  8 19:07   still logged in
joeuser  ttys009                   Sun Apr  7 15:54   still logged in
joeuser  ttys005                   Sun Apr  7 15:37   still logged in
joeuser  ttys011                   Sun Apr  7 10:10 - 10:10  (00:00)
joeuser  ttys012                   Sun Apr  7 08:57 - 08:57  (00:00)
joeuser  ttys011                   Sun Apr  7 08:56 - 08:56  (00:00)
joeuser  ttys011                   Sat Apr  6 23:25 - 23:25  (00:00)
joeuser  ttys009                   Fri Apr  5 14:59 - 14:59  (00:00)
joeuser  ttys011                   Fri Apr  5 00:04 - 00:04  (00:00)
```

This output will also show reboots & shutdowns too. For eg:

```
$ last | grep -E "reboot|shutdown" | head
reboot    ~                         Tue Mar 26 22:10
shutdown  ~                         Tue Mar 26 22:07
root      console                   Tue Mar 26 22:06 - shutdown  (00:00)
reboot    ~                         Tue Mar 26 21:57
shutdown  ~                         Tue Mar 26 21:54
root      console                   Tue Mar 26 21:52 - shutdown  (00:01)
reboot    ~                         Fri Mar  8 07:23
reboot    ~                         Fri Feb 22 10:34
reboot    ~                         Fri Feb  8 10:51
shutdown  ~                         Fri Feb  8 10:45
```